# How to disable MacOs Maverick app nap on a binary or test runtime environments

Tags: apache-flex, testing, osx-mavericks

I am using MacOs Maverick for development. We have a nice test suite that requires roughly 8 minutes to finish. We have asynchronous calls with timeouts if we do not get a respond in time.

Everything works fine if I keep the focus on the test runner environment which is in my particular case adl from flex SDK. As soon as I switch to a different application the available resources for this particular process get reduced and our events no longer trigger in time. This causes a lot failures.

I know you can disable App Nap for applications via the info dialog but you do not have the same option for adl or any other executable that is not defined as ".app".

Comment: +1 Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124464/disabling-app-nap-in-mavericks applicable globally which is good enough for development.